# With SSIS, how do you export SQL results to multiple CSV files?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

In my SSIS package, I have an Execute SQL Task that is supposed to return up to one hundred million (100,000,000) rows.

I would like to export these results to multiple CSV files, where each file has a maximum of 500,000 rows. So if the SQL task generates 100,000,000 results, I would like to produce 200 csv files with 500,000 records in each.

What are the best SSIS tasks that can automatically partition the results into many exported CSV files?

I am currently developing a script task but find that it's not very performant.  I am a bit new to SSIS so I am not familiar with all the different tasks available, and I'm wondering if maybe there's another one that can do it much more efficiently.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Static approach

First add a dataflow task.

In the dataflow task add the following:

1. A source: in the screenshot ADO NET Source. That contains the query to retrieve the data
2. A conditional split: Every condtion you add will result in a blue output arrow. You need to connect every arrow to a destination
3. Excel destination or flat file destiation. Depending if you want Excel files or csv files. For CSV files you'll need to setup a file connection.

[image: Dataflow with conditional split]

In the conditional split you can add multiple conditions to split out your data and have a default output.

[image: Conditional split]

Flat file connection manager:
[image: Flat file connection manager]

### Dynamic approach

1. Use Execute SQL Task to retrieve the variables to start a for loop. (BatchSize, Start, End)
2. Add a for / foreach
3. Add a dataflow task in the loop, pass in the parameters from the loop.
   (You can pass parameters/expressions to sub process in the dataflow using the expressions property. [image: expressions on dataflow])
4. Fetch the data with a source in a dataflow task based on the parameters from the for loop.
5. Write to a destination (Excel/CSV) with a dynamic name based from the parameters of the loop.

[image: Dynamic approach]